# what to do with system installed python versions when starting with pythonbrew

Tags: ubuntu, python

I'm running Ubuntu 11.10. I have both Python 2.7 and 3.2 installed on the system and available in /usr/bin/. I am looking to start using pythonbrew and it seems it will want me to install my python versions in my user directory. Do I need to do anything with the currently installed versions python? the info on pythonbrew that I can find doesn't really mention the legacy versions of python that might be installed on a system.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have a symlink at /usr/bin/python pointing  to either /usr/bin/python3.2 or /usr/bin/python.2.6

When you type "python" at the command line, it will search the folders in the PATH and exectute the first python it finds - the one in /usr/bin right now, which is a symlink so will run either python2.6 or python3.2

If you install other version of python in your home folder, then provided the python exectutable for these installations are earlier in the PATH than the system one, it will be run in its place.

An alternative would be to run the installed version of python by specifying the path, in which case the PATH variable is not considered - for example:

```
/home/user/pythonbrew/python2.6/python
```

You can always run a local version in preference to a system version, so you don't need to do anything about them.